# Any way to make a note block keep its note?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am currently playing on Minecraft Version 8.1, and I went on creative to try to make a song with Note Blocks. Little did I know, each time you click the note block, it changes its note!

So, is there any way to lock a Note Block's note so that it won't change? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hitting the block (Left mouse button) makes it play. Activating it (right mouse button) changes the note- this also plays the new note as a preview. When you're playing your song, only use the left mouse button- this will keep the notes the same.

You can also activate note blocks with redstone, using buttons or pressure plates. This can allow you to play several notes at once or even play a tune automatically. Playing the note with redstone is the same as hitting the block- the note will never change.

Answer (score -1):

Use red stone to activate them that’ll help set the note yourself and then use the red stone to keep the same note

Comment: Thanks for your contribution Finley! It appears that this information is already in the accepted answer. Is there anything that you'd like to add that isn't already in the accepted answer?